# Related to calendar list webpart

Tags: web-part, list

I am getting below error when I select a past date (ex : may21) in my calendar list webpart 
Data at the root level is invalid.Line 1, position 1. (9357c51d-202e-4a83-8ef5-d77324f4e989)

After checking the logs I got the error as 
"w3wp.exe (0x1CF8) 016CC    SharePoint Foundation       General                     e7dc    Monitorable

Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)     at

System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()     at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()     at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc,

XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)     at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)     at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)     at

Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Calendar.RecurrenceRule..ctor(String rule)     at

Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Calendar.RecurrenceItemExpander.ExpandSeriesItem(SPItem masterItem, String beginFieldName, String endFieldName, DateTime

localTimeRangeBegin, DateTime localTimeRangeEnd, SPTimeZone localTZ)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Ca... 436bf880-129a-405c-9e3e-8b91535a87b8

Anyone please help me

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the same problem so I thought I would post an answer even if the question is old. This error happens when the XML definition of the recurrence of one of the calendar items is invalid. In my case, I don't know how it happened, but one of the items had a value of "Every 1 day(s)" instead of

```
<recurrence>
    <rule>
        <firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek>
        <repeat>
            <daily dayFrequency="1" />
        </repeat>
        <repeatForever>FALSE</repeatForever>
    </rule>
</recurrence>
```

To fix the issue, you can go in the All Events view, find the item with an invalid recurrence value and set it to something valid.